# What's the most efficient way to get distinct rows in a data table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table that has lots of rows.

I'm considering different options for taking a unique set of rows including

```
dt <- dt %>% unique(.)
dt <- dt %>% distinct()
```

What's the most efficient ways to do this? I'm concerned about efficiency because it's a 20GB file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unique will probably be the most efficient, since there is a data.table implementation.

Example data (250m rows, 2 columns).

```
library("data.table")

# Setting the number of threads to something reasonable for the benchmark.
# You don't need to normally set this. 
setDTthreads(6)

DT <- data.table(
  obj=sample(LETTERS[1:10], 2.5e8, replace=TRUE),
  val=sample(seq_len(10), 2.5e8, replace=TRUE)
)

> print(object.size(DT), units="Gb")
2.8 Gb
```

Benchmark.

```
bench::mark(distinct=distinct(DT), unique=unique(DT), iterations=5)

# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression   min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 distinct   5.28s   5.4s     0.185    2.93GB    0.123     3     2     16.24s
2 unique     1.91s  1.97s     0.504  953.69MB    0         5     0      9.93s
# … with 4 more variables: result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

Comment: data.table will by default use all threads, so unless you have a compelling reason to limit it, I wouldn't worry about setting this. I only switched it to 6 since I felt my default value was much higher than what most people would be working with. I'll edit the answer to better reflect this.

Comment: data.table uses *half* the number of threads by default